# How to connect three classes in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

Hello can u tell me how to create LINQ syntax  with classes:

```
// Client:   int ID, string Name
// Item:     int ID, float Price
// Purchase: int ClientID, int ItemID
```

to get Names of Clients who spent more than 100 (Sum of their item price)

```
    static List<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client {Id=1, Name="Jon" },
            new Client {Id=2, Name="Ben" },
            new Client {Id=3, Name="Tom" },
            new Client {Id=4, Name="Sara" },
        };
    }

    static List<Item> GetItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id=1, Price = 8f },
            new Item {Id=2, Price = 8f },
            new Item {Id=3, Price = 75f },
            new Item {Id=4, Price = 33.33f },
            new Item {Id=5, Price = 82.5f },
            new Item {Id=6, Price = 25f },
        };
    }

    static List<Purchase> GetPurchases()
    {
        return new List<Purchase>
        {
            new Purchase(1,1),
            new Purchase(1,2),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(3,5),
            new Purchase(3,6),
            new Purchase(4,2),
            new Purchase(4,2),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(6,4),
            new Purchase(6,1)
        };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var clients = GetClients();
        var items = GetItems();
        var purchases = GetPurchases();

       // need LINQ here
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind to tell us how the classes belong together?

Comment: More specifically, LINQ works with _collections_ of data. What kind of collections do you have with the above? Do you have collections of purchases, collections of customers, collections of items? What does your code look like?

Comment: just write in a console Names of these clients who spent more than specified Sum of item_price they spent , all in static List<>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client {Id=1, Name="Jon" },
            new Client {Id=2, Name="Ben" },
            new Client {Id=3, Name="Tom" },
            new Client {Id=4, Name="Sara" },
        };
        }

        static List<Item> GetItems()
        {
            return new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id=1, Price = 8f },
            new Item {Id=2, Price = 8f },
            new Item {Id=3, Price = 75f },
            new Item {Id=4, Price = 33.33f },
            new Item {Id=5, Price = 82.5f },
            new Item {Id=6, Price = 25f },
        };
        }

        static List<Purchase> GetPurchases()
        {
            return new List<Purchase>
        {
            new Purchase(1,1),
            new Purchase(1,2),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(2,3),
            new Purchase(3,5),
            new Purchase(3,6),
            new Purchase(4,2),
            new Purchase(4,2),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(5,3),
            new Purchase(6,4),
            new Purchase(6,1)
        };
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Client> clients = GetClients();
            List<Item> items = GetItems();
            List<Purchase> purchases = GetPurchases();

            var results = (from p in purchases
                           join c in clients on p.ClientID equals c.Id
                           join i in items on p.ItemID equals i.Id
                           select new { purchase = p, client = c, item = i })
                          .GroupBy(x => x.client)
                          .Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.item.Price) > 100)
                          .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().client.Name)
                          .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class Purchase
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }

        public Purchase(int item, int client)
        {
            ItemID = item;
            ClientID = client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: purchases should be populated by `GetPurchases()` somewhere, right?

Comment: I updated code to match Rufus changes.